# The pth power of a distance function is twice continuously differentiable, for $p>2$?

Tags: real-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Suppose $\mathcal{O}$ is an open convex connected strict subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define $\beta(x)=dist(x, \mathcal{O})$, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is $\beta^p$, $p>2$ a twice continuously differentiable fuction? if the answer is no, what about assuming moreover $\mathcal{O}$ is bounded?

Could you pls give some hints for proof?

Thank you!

Comment: Gerald Edgar has given an counter-example to show it does not hold true when $\mathcal{O}$ is not connected. Thank you!

Now I have changed a little the condition. I would like to know if I suppose that $\mathcal{O}$ is connected, it holds true or not.

Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: Convexity is an assumption that may give you something, as stressed by Tom Bachmann below, connectivity is not.


Comment: Thank you all for your answers, especially to Benoît Kloeckner and Tom Bachmann. 

May I ask if we add a assumption of convexity on this domain, is there any hint of proof?

Answer (score 2):

How about in $\mathbb R$ the open set is $(-2,-1) \cup (1,2)$.  Study $\beta(x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: You are right! 

Would you please help to think it when $\mathcal{O}$ is required to be connected?

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference, just consider the same example in the plane and "close up" the two bits via a "connection far enough out" (i.e. a something like a thickened semi-circular arc in the upper half plane).